# list.extend method applied while creating the list

Tags: python, list

`Python` `list.extend()` method allows to append a list to an existing one, as detailed [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

I can do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
a = [1,2,3]
a.extend(list(np.arange(4,20,1)))
```

but I **cannot** make this work:

```
a = [1,2,3].extend(list(np.arange(4,20,1)))
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

It's contained in my selected answer, but I will spell it out for people who, like me, were really missing the point of why this cannot work.

The code that does not produce the intended result contains an assigment:

`a = <something>`

This means that on the right-hand side of the `=` there **must** be a valid expression, otherwise the assignment is void.

However, the `list.extend()` method **does not return anything**, it just modifies the original list.

So, the operation:

```
[1,2,3].extend(list(np.arange(4,20,1)))
```

does modify `[1,2,3]` but there's no reference to this list, so this is an object that there's no way to retrieve. This is why the second code in my question does not work, and the first one does. It's because in the first one I **do** create a reference to the `[1,2,3]` list, with `a = [1,2,3]`.

Comment: That would depend, in part, on what language you are using.

Comment: Where did you learn that `extend` returns anything?

Comment: The fact that to assign (a = ...) you need the right-hand to actually return something just escaped me. Thanks for pointing that out so politely, I now understand where the problem lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a = [1,2,3].extend(list(np.arange(4,20,1)))

`list.extend()` doesn't return anything, it modifes the original list. You can only do something like

```py
a = [1,2,3] + list(np.arange(4,20,1))
```

or

```py
a = [1,2,3]
a.extend(list(np.arange(4,20,1)))
```